# Vim-Syntastic showing ignored python errors

Tags: vim, syntastic, flake8, vim-syntastic

`Syntastic` and `flake8` in `vim` not ignoring errors provided in `flake8` config file.

I am using `flake8` for python code linting with `Syntastic` in `vim`. I have a `flake8` config file per `flake8` documentation `absolute_path_to_home/.config/flake8` which ignores error `E251`. Now, when I run `flake8` from command line  by typing

```
flake8 --config=absolute_path_to_home/.config/flake8 my_python_code_that_is_being_checked.py
```

then `flake8` ignores the error `E251`. However, when I run `flake8` inside vim using `<F7>` the error window inside vim shows `E251` despite it being ignored in the `flake8` config file.

To make sure that `Syntastic` is calling the `flake8` with right arguments I added the following to my `.vimrc`

```
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['flake8']
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args='--config=absolute_path_to_home/.config/flake8'
let g:syntastic_debug = 1
```

I checked the `Syntastic` call inside `vim` using `:messages` and get the following info

```
syntastic: 4.483755: CacheErrors: Invoking checker: python/flake8
syntastic: 4.484046: SyntasticMake: called with options: {'errorformat': '%E%f:%l: could not compile,%-Z%p^,%A%f:%l:%c: %m,%A%f:%l: %m,%-G%.%#', 
'makeprg':'flake8 --config=absolute_path_to_home/.config/flake8 my_python_code_that_is_being_checked.py', 'env': {'TERM': 'dumb'}}
syntastic: 4.615727: system: command run in 0.131497s
syntastic: 4.617432: getLocList: checker python/flake8 returned 1
syntastic: 4.618452: getLocList: checker python/flake8 run in 0.134634s
```

So if the message above is to be believed then `Syntastic` is indeed calling `flake8` with the right config file so I am not sure why `E251` is still being displayed. For good measures below is what my `absolute_path_to_home/.config/flake8` file

```
[flake8]
ignore = E251
```

Is this a known bug? What am I doing wrong? Will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Syntastic issue tracker is [here](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues).